# Get number of elements in a JQuery Sortable list

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-sortable, content-length

The API of JQuery Sortable isn't clear on how to retrieve the number of elements in a sortable list.
The reason I want the number of elements, is because I want to set the position of a widget to the end of the sortable list. I know there is an append function, but I have my own logic to manipulate the sortable list.

Does someone know how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$('#sortable li').length;
```

since `$(foo)` returns either a jQuery object or an array of jQuery objects, depending on the selector `foo`, you can use the .length attribute.

Comment: I would like to thank everyone for their help. I used this answer and it worked fine:)

Answer (score 3):

you could use [toArray](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-toArray) method and check the length of the result array

Comment: I like this method because my sortable is using divs, not li elements.  I could use a version ofZim84's answer above with $("#sortable div").length, but why not let the sortable function keep track of its own child length.  So -- $("#" + divID).sortable("toArray").length works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I think this might not be implemented in the jQuery sortable plugin (I haven't checked though), because just standard jQuery can count your list items.

for example:

`var count = $("#myList li).length`

gets you the number of records in the list `<ul id="myList">`